# Drupal - Search showing preg_match error

Tags: php, drupal

I have a custom search going on in one of the website I am building in Drupal. Search works perfectly fine when the "Rebuild theme registry on every page." checkbox is selected on the Theme Configure page. However, when I uncheck it (for production), the search no longer works, the same page just reloads again on hitting the search button. Upon looking at the Recent Log Entries I found the error:
preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/devel_sites/SITENAME/docroot/modules/search/search.module on line 671.

Anybody got any ideas why my search would be depending upon the theme registry and how to fix this? I have a custom module for search and part of the functionality is in template.php.

Any tips are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you have theme developer or devel enabled, disable them and try again

Comment: I didn't have them installed and it was showing the error. In fact, I just installed them thinking I could get some help from them but no luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was (finally) able to resolve the issue and I am posting the resolution below in case someone else faces the same.

I started by moving all the functional logic from template.php to my custom module (I should have done it anyways and it seemed like it might be an issue) but it didn't solve it. I had to dig in my custom module code and that's where I found what the problem was. I was using the following to get the entered keywords:

`$form_state['values']['processed_keys']`

It turns out, when Rebuild Theme registry option is turned off, the above array value is overwritten by the theme registry and is being replaced by an empty array, hence causing the error in line 671 of the search module which, is expecting a string as the second argument, and not an array. Replacing the above with the below solved it for me:

`$form['basic']['inline']['processed_keys']['#post']['keys']`

Answer (score 0):

Without posting code (since the code is custom,) I don't think anyone can answer your question satisfactorily. However, if you don't mind modifying module code, simply do a `is_array` conditional before line 671 and if it is, `implode` the terms (or inspect it and get rid of any garbage.) Pass that string on to line 671.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I actually went that route just for testing purposes. I did print_r($keys) ($keys is the second argument for preg_match in line 671) and it actually is just an empty array. So only when the 'Rebuild Theme Registry on every page' option is turned OFF, the $keys variable is (may I call it) corrupted and being passed as an empty array, when the option is turned ON, $keys returns the typed search keywords and everything is fine. Maybe, there is some way that I can exclude the search from being dependent on the theme registry?

Comment: Where is `$keys` coming from? Is there a variable called `$keys` somewhere in theme registry? `$keys` is getting overwritten somehow.

Comment: $keys is the variable used in search.module and (looks like) it is getting its value from my custom search module. I checked in the theme registry using the devel module (on the /devel/theme/registry page) but I don't see any $keys variable/array there. That is basically what's happening, the search value from my custom module is being overwritten, being replaced by an empty array somewhere and somehow related to the theme registry, and, being referenced on line 671 (by $keys) , but how should I check/confirm that and more importantly find out where it is happening?

Comment: @Navneet You'll need to either search through the code yourself, following where everything is going (using a debugger would be way easier than trying to do it manually,) or do a backtrace.